# What template to choose for a minimalist IIS web application that needs a web.config and a single HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, windows-authentication, iis-10

I haven't been developing ASP.NET applications for 7 or 8 years and a lot has changed.  What template should I choose in Visual Studio if the web app has *no UI* and all that's required is

```
-- web.config
-- an HttpHandler (formerly an ashx)
-- Windows authentication
-- authorization role is an Active Directory Security Group
```

Comment: Why not use ASP.NET Core instead?

Comment: Probably something along the lines of MVC/Web API.  What do you intend on returning, JSON/XML responses?

Comment: Json responses.

Comment: @Tim you could use asp.net mvc project to implement your requirement.